# What is $\log_{1}{(1)}$ ? Is it undefined or can be any real number?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Is $\log_{1}{(1)}$ **undefined** or can be **any real number**. Let me explain

When we ask what is $\frac{0}{0}$. The answer comes out to be **undefined**. This follows immediately from the definition of division of two number $a,b$ which says that $\frac{a}{b}$ is the unique solution to the equation $x\times b=a$. Now if we put $a=b=0$ i.e. $\frac{0}{0}$ what we are looking for is the unique solution to the equation $x\times 0=0$. At first sight it might seem that answer can be **any real number** but according to definition answer should be unique and since answer is not coming unique so we say answer is not any number or **undefined**

Now I come to the question of $log_{1}{(1)}$ . When we ask what is $log_{a}{(b)}$ what we mean is the solution(not sure is it unique or not) to the equation $a^x=b$ and if $a=b=1$ then solution(not sure unique or not) to equation $1^x=1$ . Now the whole thing depends upon my being unsure about whether the definition includes unique solution(to $a^x=b$) in case of logarithms also as it is in the case of division.

It’s  very clear that if definition includes the “unique” solution to $a^x=b$ (as in the case of division) then answer to $log_{1}{(1)}$ will be **undefined** and if this is not the case then the answer will be **any real number**.

So does we include the word “unique” or not and thus answer is **undefined** or **any real number**.

Comment: We usually don't talk about base-1 logs, because the function $f(x)=1^x$ is not invertible.

Comment: There is a strong reason to also call this undefined, because it would be equivalent to  $\frac{\ln 1}{\ln 1}$, i.e., $\frac00$.

Comment: You ask if it can be defined as any real number. Are there *any* functions that are defined as any real number at some point?

Comment: @gen-z ready to perish so does that mean $\log_{a}{b}$ is the **unique** solution to the equation $b^x=a$ and since this equation(in case of $a,b=1$ ) doesn’t have a unique solution therefore it’s undefined?

Answer (score 3):

$f(x) = \log_b(x)$ is defined to be the inverse of the exponential function $g(x) =b^x$. Since $x \mapsto 1^x$ is not injective, it does not have an inverse. Hence $\log_{1}(x)$ is not well-defined.

Answer (score 2):

The expression $\log_1(1)$ is the "logarithmic equivalent" of $0/0$.

You may have heard of the rule
$$\log_x(y)=\frac{\log_a(x)}{\log_a(y)}$$
for any $a,x,y$ for which all of the expressions are defined. If you set $x,y=1$ and $a$ to be some non-one value, you get that $\log_1(1)$ *should be*
$$\frac{\log_a(1)}{\log_a(1)}=\frac 00.$$
When we define $\log_x(y)$ as "the unique number $a$ so that $x^a=y$," we run into the error you mentioned where $1^a=1$ for all real $a$. Similarly, when we define $x/y$ as "the unique number $a$ so that $ay=x$," we run into the error where $0\cdot a = 0$ for all $a$. It's the same issue, just in the exponent.

As such, we say that $\log_1(1)$, like $0/0$, is **undefined**.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think logarithms are defined for base 1.

Specifically, since $\log_a{b}=\frac{1}{\log_b{a}}$,

we can consider $\log_x{1}=0$, using the above property above: $\log_1{x}=\frac{1}{\log_x{1}}=\frac{1}{0}$

Comment: You can define logarithms for any positive base other than $1$. A logarithm base $\frac{1}{2}$ makes sense, since $\log_{1/2}(x) = r$ just means that $r$ is the unique real number such that $(1/2)^r = x$. From this, you see that $\log_{1/2}(x) = -\log_2(x)$.

Comment: Thank you, I have edited my answer to prevent confusion for the poster.